# Timer Issue with display pop up

Tags: javascript

The Timer displayed is 1 hr (HH:MM:SS) in decrement order. I have to display a pop out when 50 minutes complete after that remaining 10 minutes one pop up should display saying 10 minutes with 0 sec.

After that for every 2 minutes the pop up appear showing 2 minutes left remaining time out.

Example: It was showing 8 minutes left for time out, but the pop should appear with 8 minutes left.

Comment: assuming this is javascript, since it's talking about pop ups.

Comment: share some code or your effort for it.